# importing OS in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

Im Getting Into Wxpython And Really Learning Some Cool Stuff About It And How It Works.
Now I Have Recently Just Quit Tkinter For The Fact That It Didnt Suit My Taste.

The Question I Would Like To Ask.
And Its A Very Noob Question.
So Bear With Me.

Is How Do You Import Your Operating Systems Commands Within A "Wxpython Button" Or Even A Menu Item?

For Example In Tkinter It Goes Like This

def Class():
  os.system("echo 'Hello Im Running Linux And How Would You Import Me In Wxpython' ")

Im Running Linux So I Wanted To Know If You Could Import Bash Shell Within Wxpython.

Thanks Everyone.

Dave.

Comment: Im fascinated by your capitalizations alone.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is... There is no difference. Whether you are using tkinter, wxpython, pyqt, gtk, they are all still python. They all still have some form of a callback that is attached to say a button press event. So the same way you import the os module and call os.system does not change. Take a look at this link talking about callbacks in wxpython : http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks

You will notice that its again just a bind command that connects a callback function to an event. Inside that callback you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Ok thanks man a bunch. 
just getting into python so forgive the noob.
thanks for everything.

Comment: No problem. Was this more a question about callbacks? I recommend checking out a tutorial. You will find that alot of these gui frameworks are very similar. Also, if you are just learning python recently as well, jumping into a gui might be too much of a complexity right away. You have to understand some extra stuff like classes, inheritence, and things that are a step down the road

Comment: yea man it was prrob a question about callbacks 
and your right i need to look into all the modules and frameworks before GUI.
so like i said man thanks for everything.
you have been a help

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems, as if you were trying to do something, that you shouldn't do anyway.
If you directly mix the view with the functionality, you will have to fight many problems later on.

So it is recommended to put the os function calls in a separate class, and to let the button call a function of that class.

I suggest reading about the Model View Controller Pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Although this answer really has nothing to so with his question. You are just suggesting he change his style while he is learning